# Android Development: Launcher/Splash activity got stuck and logs throwing resume of activity record INDEFINITELY

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, android-activity

Another time for an noob question on Android Development.
I have again encountered a blocker as I study mobile development for Android.

I have created a personal project/exercise for 2 months now and it was working smoothly.
Then come one day (yesterday) when my app stopped working.
By "stopped", I meant, whenever I try running my Android App project, it triggers my first activity (launcher or splash screen), but it got stuck there.

My splash screen only has a very simple code to redirect to the next activity (below), but for whatever reason it does not do so.

Note that it was working perfectly and only made a few tweaks (specifically adding "animation" to a TextView), but just one day it stopped. A BIG mystery to me.

Note also, as I thought it was due to my Eclipse IDE, so I decided to use the most recent Android Studio tool, but killing my excitement when I tried running it (after recreating the same codes manually), it still did not work.

Really am looking forward to any help guys, as this has been killing me like I want to punch my face hard. :-(

Codes and logs below:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

Intent mainIntent;

Animation fadeIn;
TextView txt_AppTagLine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    mainIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);

    fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f , 1.0f ) ;
    fadeIn.setDuration(1500);
    fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
    txt_AppTagLine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_AppTagline);
    txt_AppTagLine.startAnimation(fadeIn);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Splash.this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
        }
    }, 3000);
}

}
```

I tried removing the animation (which I remember to be the last thing that I added before the issue), but still the same.

Below are the logs which strangely shows repeating and indefinite (probably infinite) messages:

```
12-30 21:32:22.890  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: ResumeAll waking others
12-30 21:32:22.890  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: ResumeAll complete
12-30 21:32:22.891  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1684K (21178), 4% free 52805K/54528K, paused 329ms, total 329ms
12-30 21:32:22.911  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{44dafa68 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44daf0f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:22.911  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{44dafa68 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44daf0f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:22.911  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{44dafa68 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44daf0f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:22.912  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{44dafa68 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44daf0f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:23.607  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44daf0f8
12-30 21:32:23.785  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{4490c580 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44bccf80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}: app=android.app.Application@41e45930, appName=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, pkg=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, comp={com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}, dir=/data/app/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp-1.apk
12-30 21:32:23.805  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{4490c580 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44bccf80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:23.806  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{4490c580 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44bccf80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:23.806  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{4490c580 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44bccf80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:23.806  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{4490c580 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44bccf80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:24.362  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44bccf80
12-30 21:32:24.722  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{44785f48 token=android.os.BinderProxy@449b4508 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}: app=android.app.Application@41e45930, appName=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, pkg=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, comp={com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}, dir=/data/app/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp-1.apk
12-30 21:32:24.743  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{44785f48 token=android.os.BinderProxy@449b4508 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:24.743  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{44785f48 token=android.os.BinderProxy@449b4508 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:24.743  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{44785f48 token=android.os.BinderProxy@449b4508 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:24.744  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{44785f48 token=android.os.BinderProxy@449b4508 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:25.381  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@449b4508
12-30 21:32:25.737  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{445cb4d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44826e78 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}: app=android.app.Application@41e45930, appName=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, pkg=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, comp={com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}, dir=/data/app/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp-1.apk
12-30 21:32:25.758  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{445cb4d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44826e78 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:25.758  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{445cb4d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44826e78 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:25.758  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{445cb4d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44826e78 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:25.759  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{445cb4d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44826e78 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:26.407  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44826e78
12-30 21:32:26.410  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44d5ebd0
12-30 21:32:26.410  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44d6be98
12-30 21:32:26.411  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44d7acd8
12-30 21:32:26.412  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44d87de0
12-30 21:32:26.413  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44d94ee8
12-30 21:32:26.414  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44da1ff0
12-30 21:32:26.414  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44daf0f8
12-30 21:32:26.416  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44bccf80
12-30 21:32:26.416  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@449b4508
12-30 21:32:26.715  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{4420da38 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44751838 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}: app=android.app.Application@41e45930, appName=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, pkg=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, comp={com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}, dir=/data/app/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp-1.apk
12-30 21:32:26.903  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{4420da38 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44751838 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:26.903  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{4420da38 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44751838 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:26.903  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{4420da38 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44751838 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:26.903  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{4420da38 token=android.os.BinderProxy@44751838 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:27.545  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@44751838
12-30 21:32:27.924  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{43bf9c58 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4414c5f0 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}: app=android.app.Application@41e45930, appName=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, pkg=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, comp={com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}, dir=/data/app/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp-1.apk
12-30 21:32:27.947  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{43bf9c58 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4414c5f0 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:27.948  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{43bf9c58 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4414c5f0 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:27.948  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{43bf9c58 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4414c5f0 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:27.948  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{43bf9c58 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4414c5f0 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:28.588  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@4414c5f0
12-30 21:32:28.942  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{441963d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@442e6df8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}: app=android.app.Application@41e45930, appName=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, pkg=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, comp={com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}, dir=/data/app/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp-1.apk
12-30 21:32:28.964  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{441963d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@442e6df8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:28.964  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{441963d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@442e6df8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:28.964  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{441963d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@442e6df8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:28.964  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{441963d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@442e6df8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:29.606  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@442e6df8
12-30 21:32:29.960  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{431abc30 token=android.os.BinderProxy@43d9cd80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}: app=android.app.Application@41e45930, appName=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, pkg=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, comp={com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}, dir=/data/app/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp-1.apk
12-30 21:32:29.984  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{431abc30 token=android.os.BinderProxy@43d9cd80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:29.984  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{431abc30 token=android.os.BinderProxy@43d9cd80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:29.984  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{431abc30 token=android.os.BinderProxy@43d9cd80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:29.985  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{431abc30 token=android.os.BinderProxy@43d9cd80 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:30.627  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@43d9cd80
12-30 21:32:30.990  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{44b36db8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@446179f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}: app=android.app.Application@41e45930, appName=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, pkg=com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp, comp={com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}, dir=/data/app/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp-1.apk
12-30 21:32:31.010  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{44b36db8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@446179f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} finished=true
12-30 21:32:31.010  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{44b36db8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@446179f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: true
12-30 21:32:31.010  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{44b36db8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@446179f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
12-30 21:32:31.011  17139-17139/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{44b36db8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@446179f8 {com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp/com.robearthsoftworks.exerciseapp.Login}}
```

Thanks again in advance guys and I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your `Login` activity doing?

Comment: I would also move the postDelayed code to onResume

Comment: @laalto - Login activity, i would say has nothing special on it. I also tried removing all the logic on the Login part, but still the same. Also tried making the "Login" activity as the launcher, but what happened, all the views (textview, and button) are not showing. still i am 95% sure that it is not the Login activity.

Comment: @AssafGamliel - will try that and let you know, thanks.

Comment: @RobEarthSoftworks How did it go?

Comment: @AssafGamliel - it did not work man... still desperately searching on the net. i have a wild guess though, it seems that when i started using something from appcompat7 library (for the ActionBarActivity in particular), it somewhat caused it; but not 100% sure though. any chance you know if that can cause error on launch in any way? note that my Splash activity nor the next activity (Login) does not use ActionBarActivity; but by another activity (not yet interacted to).

Comment: Looks like the problem is in `Login` activity. Post the code for that.

Comment: @DavidWasser - YOU ARE A GENIUS MAN!!! It is the Login activity indeed that is causing it!!! Whew! Or am I just very hard-headed. Stupid me! it turns out, I have the codes below on my OnCreate of Login activity, they are the culprit:
        Login.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        Login.this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);

whew! thanks man! will mark this as resolved... and I have already messed up my project. LOL!
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it is actually the "Login" activity which is the next activity that is causing the problem.
For whatever reason, a stupid person (ME) pasted the below code causing an infinite loop obviously.

```
Login.this.startActivity(mainIntent); 
Login.this.finish(); 
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
```

Will close this question, and thanks guys for the immediate answers and interest.